# My own API Key to my RPC server

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have my service (RPC based on JSON) that I want to protect from being abused by not allowed programmers.

I know that many APIs use system of private/public API Key, that when 1 key is abusing connection they can kill only this one service. How to do this in easy and fast way? Mainly I need only information which algorithms should I use to generate and check keys and when (on initiating connection or maybe to every request).

In addition I use Google AppEngine with Python as server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick/easy way is to generate a unique key for each developer who has access to your service:

```
import random, string

key = "".join([random.choice(string.letters + string.digits + string.punctuation) for _ in xrange(64)])
```

And have the user include this key on every request they make to your service (you can track the usage based on the key and ban abused keys)

This is the most basic method. If you require more than just API Key tracking, such as encryption and/or authorization, you can chose from established protocols available online (e.g. OAuth)

Comment: If generating a unique key is all you want you might want to have a look at uuid. http://docs.python.org/library/uuid.html

Comment: how should this answer the question? he is asking for how to generate and *check* keys. generating a key and including it in responses does not protect anything.

Comment: @aschmid00 - When the user includes the provided key in the request, you just parse it out (in whatever format the service runs, in this case as a JSON variable) and check that key against the datastore. I didn't include any code to save the key to the user model because the OP was on how to generate a key and check it, I assume storing this key on a per User basis was obvious. Checking a key is trivial given the method I proposed.